# Proof that BitTorrent is secure for deploying server code and data files to many servers

Tags: bittorrent

Is using BitTorrent module for distributing server code and data files to internal server machines secure? Of course, the server code and data files are confidential stuff, and never to be leaving the server private network.

This is my rough proof: Distributing files to many internal servers using BitTorrent module (e.g. [LibTorrent](https://www.libtorrent.org/)) is secure, unless Magnet nor Torrent file is disclosed to a hacker. Of course, Magnet or Torrent file is to be kept always secure, thus, using BitTorrent is secure.

There is a [news](https://torrentfreak.com/facebook-uses-bittorrent-and-they-love-it-100625/) that Facebook uses BitTorrent module for deploying server code and data files to many internal servers.

Is my proof right? I have to tell the proof to my colleagues.

Comment: What do you want to protect against? Data being tampered with, or data not leaving your network?

Comment: data not leaving your network. I modified the question. @NilsWerner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *proof* that data won't leave your network, because data leaving your network can be entirely orthogonal to your choice of distributing data: any computer can get hacked and can send data to the outside world, no matter how it was received.

However, if you're asking if you can

1. restrict your BitTorrent data to your network,
2. safeguard yourself against eaversdroppers within your network, and
3. protect your data against tampering mid-transfer,

you should be able to do so.

Firstly, you can **contain data transfers** by setting up your firewalls correctly:

1. Prevent access to the tracker from outside the network
2. Prevent access to BitTorrent ports to all of your clients from outside the network
3. Disable DHT for your Torrents
4. Disable UPnP in your clients

If you do this correctly, even leaking the Magnet link or `.torrent` file will only reveal the filenames, checksums and your internal tracker and client IPs, but not any of the contents.

To protect against a **third party listening to your internal network data**, you should enable Protocol Encryption. However note that PE is only meant to obfuscate BitTorrent traffic, it might not be 100% attack-resilient.

Lastly, BitTorrent comes with a protection against a **third party trying to inject their own data** and distribute malicious packages in your network this way. BitTorrent prevents this by distributing checksums in the `.torrent` file. However, it is crucial that you **prevent tampering with the `.torrent` file**, which can be solved easily by using HTTPS for the Tracker.

Needless to say, using BitTorrent will definitely increase your [attack surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface), but it won't be inherently unsafe.

Twitter was also using BitTorrent to distribute files to their servers. They even open sourced their implementation, called [murder](https://github.com/lg/murder).

Answer (score 1):

As a dissent to @Nils Werner:

The obfuscation scheme (known as protocol encryption) built into many bittorrent clients *explicitly* is not a scheme to ensure data confidentiality. It relies on weak diffie hellman exchanges and a RC4 stream cipher is is largely considered broken.

If you cannot trust the network link between the servers and your data needs to be kept confidential you should either encrypt it at rest before creating the torrents or use [libtorrent](https://www.libtorrent.org/manual-ref.html#ssl-torrents)'s non-standard TLS transport feature.

If confidentiality against an internal attacker is not a concern (know your [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model)!) and you only need integrity checking then bittorrent usually is sufficient unless [collision attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) are a concern since SHA1 is only considered to have preimage resistance now, not collision resistance.

If you're only concerned about accidental leaks to the internet then neither of these points are particularly relevant. But you may want use the [private flag](http://the%20private%20flag%20in%20torrents) which instructs the client to only use the tracker as peer source. The downside is that it also disables peer exchange and local service discovery, which may be useful even in internal networks.